# "InvalidServerResponse" during post request to the NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, postman

i'm new to nodeJS.
I got this message in my console while sending post request from the postman to my nodejs application.

**App is listening on port: 9000
InvalidServerResponse**

code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var moment = require('moment');
var _ = require('underscore');
var fs = require('fs');
var HttpStatus = require('http-status');
var FCM = require('fcm-push');
var serverKey ="rTQq8LvUIFSbcG_6A....................";
var fcm = new FCM(serverKey);

var status = {
SUCCESS : 'success',
FAILURE : 'failure'
}

var httpStatus = {
OK : HttpStatus.OK,
ISE : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
BR : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
}
exports.likes= function(req, res){

var Username =req.body.username;
var likecount =req.body.count;
var likedby = req.body.likedby;
var postId = req.body.postId;
var tokenId = req.body.tokenId;
var message = {
                     to: tokenId, 
                     collapse_key: '',
                     data: {
                        name:Username,
                        Message:"Content about message",
                        Redirect:"TopostId : "+postId,
                        time: ""
                      },
                     notification: {
                                    title: "Hey Buddy , Someone have liked your post",
                                    body: likedby +"Likedyourpost",
                                    icon: "notification"
                                    }
                };


fcm.send(message)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
        res.status(httpStatus.OK).json({
        status: status.SUCCESS,
        code: httpStatus.OK,            
        error:''
    });
            return;
            })
        .catch(function (err) {
             console.log(err);

            });

};
```

I'm sending push notification using the Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Could you please try providing the `collapse_key` , rather than giving the empty string , it might work , hope this helps you

Comment: But it was ran perfectly few hrs ago...now only it get error

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem with 'fcm-node'. I replace the package with 'fcm-notification' Its working fine for me .

Comment: for people wandering in here from some tutorial with fcm-node, you have to provide a file instead of the actual key [heres](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-notification) some help(the gif tells you everything)